# How to Display Dates in Calendar View from Database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have leave application, I need if user with level manager can view who's leave in calendar mode:

Here's the user table

```
id |   nama   |     email       |  level
1      Johan      johan.com         user
2     Michael    michael.com       manager  
3      Lorem      lorem.com       supervisor
4      Ipsum      ipsum.com     user 
5      Dolor      dolor.com     user
```

Here's the leave table

```
id |   nama   |     email       |  leave_start  |   leave_end
1      Johan      johan.com         2019-04-01     2019-04-05
5      Dolor      dolor.com     2019-04-08     2019-04-12
```

So the manager can view all data from leave table to see who's on leave. I have tried using fullcalendar following a [tutorial](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-full-calendar-tutorial-example-using-maddhatter-laravel-fullcalendar) but it's still getting an error to view the calendar.
The error is:

> Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, array given called in C:\x\htdocs\leave\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203

How I can fix these and show the data in calendar mode?

Here is code from the error on redirectresponse.php

```
public function __construct(?string $url, int $status = 302, array $headers = []) 
{ 
    parent::__construct('', $status, $headers);
    $this->setTargetUrl($url); 

    if (!$this->isRedirect()) 
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The HTTP status code is not a redirect ("%s" given).', $status)); 
    } 

    if (301 == $status && !array_key_exists('cache-control', $headers)) 
    { 
        $this->headers->remove('cache-control'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you post the code for this method: RedirectResponse::__construct()

Comment: Hi @CodeBoyCode, do you mean code from redirectresponse.php ?

Comment: yes please - it should have a __construct method in it

Comment: @IkramShabri Please add the code to your quesiton

Comment: Hi @CodeBoyCode, I've put the code on question